# how can i use standalone calendar to select date (not a datepicker) in java fx 2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

What am looking for is something as follows

[image: needed image]

and not the following one

[image: not needed image]

there are date pickers but i need fixed date selector in javafx 2.
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Just write one? It should not be difficult.

Comment: you were right bro .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  `JFxtras` [Calendar](http://jfxtras.org/images/gallery/DatePicker.png)

WebSite:[url](http://jfxtras.org/)

Comment: Singh Amarjeet Nice to hear that.If you want upload the code on github.

Comment: i wish i could .Actually i took idea from jfxtra.org and integrated in existing app.And it is official app.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented some Date & Time controls based on the Java 8 Date & Time API. They might not be yet of as high quality as the JavaFX core ones, but they should do what you are looking for: [LocalDateChooser](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.7/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/scene/control/time/LocalDateChooser.html)

The library is Open Source. Maybe you find it useful:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-time</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If you find some issues or have some enhancement requests, please file them here: https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx/issues

Here is the original blog post:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/04/drombler-commons-javafx-controls-for.html

Comment: thanks for the link man.But would you please share some github proper file link to use LocalDateFixedYearMonthChooser as mentioned in puces blog.

Comment: Javadoc: http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.7/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/scene/control/time/LocalDateFixedYearMonthChooser.html
Source: https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons/blob/develop/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-time/src/main/java/org/drombler/commons/fx/scene/control/time/LocalDateFixedYearMonthChooser.java
Sample: https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons/tree/develop/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-samples/drombler-commons-fx-samples-time